# Does Spring Boot 2.0.5 does not run Request Params

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to get in on learning the basics of spring boot 2.0 and I keep on getting a white label error when I try to add a todo item to my todo list application. Does Spring Boot 2.0 still use Request Params or is it deprecated? Because even when I try to delete a todo item I still get a white label error saying no id was passed.

My Todo Controller:

```
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    TodoService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list-todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showTodos(ModelMap modelMap) {
        String name = (String) modelMap.get("name");
        modelMap.put("todos", service.retrieveTodos(name));
        return "list-todos";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAddTodoPage(ModelMap model) {
        return "todo";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addTodo(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String desc) {
        service.addTodo((String) model.get("name"), desc, new Date(), false);
        return "redirect:/list-todos";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete-todo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteTodo(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap model) {
        model.put("id", id);
        service.deleteTodo(id);
        return "redirect:/list-todos";
    }
}
```

My todo JSP:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>add-todo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add Todo Page for ${name}</h1>

<form action="Post" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="desc">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not deprecated, Could you post your code for Controller and the HTTP request that you are trying to hit

Comment: No, it is not deprecated.

Comment: If you want help with your code, you need to post the code. As text. Not as images. We can't copy and paste from images. Some of us can't even read what is inside images.